# TcpListener not accessible from outside Android simulator

Tags: c#, android

I'm using Visual Studio to create a C# android program. I'm currently testing it in the simulator.

It creates a TcpListener to listen for incoming http connections (which happens to be 10.0.2.15:1800). The same program can connect to itself so the TcpListener works fine. Also, if I run the browser in the simulator, it too can browse to that ip/port.

However, if I try to connect to http://10.0.2.15:1800 from the host computer (ie not in the simulator) then it times out and nothing in the C# code ever gets called. I've tried disabling the windows firewall but it still fails.

Any idea what could be preventing the host computer from reaching the TcpListener?

Comment: This link contains all information you need: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html. Look at "Using network redirection" to make it working.

Comment: Thanks Evk - that solved it.